# Heimdall error libusb error: -12

Tags: rom-flashing, clockworkmod-recovery, heimdall

I have installed the C++ redistributables, but everytime I try flashing ClockworkMod Recovery, it fails with an libusb error: -12

```
C:\Users\new1\Desktop>heimdall detect
Device detected

C:\Users\new1\Desktop>heimdall flash --recovery cwm5_recovery.bin
Heimdall v1.4.0

Copyright (c) 2010-2013, Benjamin Dobell, Glass Echidna
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/

This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution is
encouraged.

If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
development please consider donating: [donate link]

Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
ERROR: Failed to access device. libusb error: -12

C:\Users\new1\Desktop>heimdall detect
Device detected
```

I have tried on all of my USB ports, even tried 3 different USB cords
Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inside Heimdall zip there is a driver folder.

- Run the zadig.exe
- click options - List All Devices
- Choose your phone from the drop down list (on my pc it was "MSM8960"

  - I could not get it to work correctly on my PC, onece plugged into laptop "SAMSUNG Mobile USB CDC Composite Device")
- Go through the drivers (WinUSB, Libusb0, Libusbk) and clikc Place drive for each of them.
- Then run Heimdall

This worked for me but I had to do it on my laptop to be able to flash the files correctly.

I still get problem installing with my phone having an issue with the downloading bar going all across the screen and then stopping the flash.

to get around this I did one file at a time and allowed it to auto reboot. Each time putting it straight into download mode.

Source: http://redialflash.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/how-to-install-and-succesful-start.html

Comment: thanks for the reminder, thats exactly what i was trying to remember.

Comment: Replace driver for *each* of them?  Meaning click it repeatedly for all of them?  Mine shows up as `Gadget Serial` twice, one of which is using the `Modem` driver and one of which is using the `dg_ssudbus` driver

Comment: https://github.com/pbatard/libwdi/wiki/Zadig says just one

Comment: For me installing the `libusb0` driver was enough for me to use Heimdall. I don't think installing each of them in turn is useful, since the last one just overwrites whatever you had installed previously, i.e. only one of them can be installed at any given time.

Comment: For me with S22 Ultra it was called just "SAMSUNG USB", and i had 2 of them, the correct one had the driver "dg_ssudbus", the wrong one had "modem-something-driver" and I replaced the correct one with WinUSB 6.1-something driver :)